# TargetReshaper.transform() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to tune my CNN's hyperparameters with Grid Search with:

```
def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu', input_shape=(178, 268, 1)))
    ...
    model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', 
        optimizer = 'adam',
        metrics = ['acc'])

    return model
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn = create_model(), verbose = 1)
epochs = [10, 20, 30]
batch_size = [40, 60, 80, 100]
param_grid = dict(batch_size = batch_size, epochs = epochs)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = model, param_grid = param_grid, n_jobs = 3,error_score = "raise", cv = 3, scoring = "accuracy")
results = grid.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

I keep getting this error and I don't know what I am doing wrong. I need to give x and y variables but it says that the function takes one argument:

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [57], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 results = grid.fit(x_train, y_train)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py:875, in BaseSearchCV.fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    869     results = self._format_results(
    870         all_candidate_params, n_splits, all_out, all_more_results
    871     )
    873     return results
--> 875 self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
   ...
-> 1389     evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
   ...
BaseSearchCV.fit.<locals>.evaluate_candidates(candidate_params, cv, more_results)
   ...
--> 822 out = parallel(
    823     delayed(_fit_and_score)(
    824         clone(base_estimator),
    825         X,
    826         y,
    827         train=train,
    828         test=test,
    829         parameters=parameters,
    830         split_progress=(split_idx, n_splits),
    831         candidate_progress=(cand_idx, n_candidates),
    832         **fit_and_score_kwargs,
    833     )
   ...
--> 1098     self.retrieve()
   ...
--> 975         self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
    976     else:
    977         self._output.extend(job.get())
   ...
--> 567     return future.result(timeout=timeout)
   ...
--> 439     return self.__get_result()
   ...
--> 391         raise self._exception
    392     finally:
    393         # Break a reference cycle with the exception in self._exception
    394         self = None

TypeError: TargetReshaper.transform() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Can someone highlight what is wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Like the error states use the raise option that gives traceback that is better to understand where the error happens. Can you add that one.

Comment: in model = KerasClassfier you are not calling create_model

Comment: hi @Daraan, I called the create_model in the KerasClassifier but unfortunately, the error has not been changed. I also detailed the error by adding the "raise" opt. Hope it would be useful. Thanks.

Comment: sorry maybe my comment that you have to call_create model is wrong, Im not sure what keras classifier expects, a model or a method to create a model

Answer (score 1):

Please check the scikeras version. The latest version 0.10.0 is not compatible with python 3.11.3. You may need to downgrade the python installation.